# Why electrons are attracted from a magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

What makes electrons to be attracted by a magnetic field ? are electrons "small" magnets ? do they create a north and south pole so they are attracted by a magnet ?

Comment: In what situation are these electrons "attracted" by a magnetic field?

Comment: Lorentz force is perpendicular to magnetic field lines.

Comment: Maybe he has in mind Landau levels?

Comment: Maybe you’re asking about electron spin?

Answer (score 1):

An electron does have a dipole moment, much like a tiny bar magnet.  A uniform magnetic field does not attract a bar magnet; it only exerts a torque on the magnet.  A magnetic field that diverges, though, can attract a bar magnet (that is why two bar magnets can attract each other).  Similarly, a diverging magnetic field can attract or repel an electron, depending on the orientation of the electron's dipole moment.  See the [Stern-Gerlach Experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment).  However, a magnetic field does not exert any force on a non-moving charge; so can interact with a stationary electron only through the electron's dipole moment.